# How can I temporarily redirect printf output to a c-string?

Tags: c, postgresql, redirect, solaris, printf

I'm writing an assignment which involves adding some functionality to PostgreSQL on a Solaris box. As part of the assignment, we need to print some information on the client side (i.e.: using `elog`.)

PostgreSQL already has lots of helper methods which print out the required information, however, the helper methods are packed with hundreds of `printf` calls, and the `elog` method only works with c-style strings.

Is there I way that I could temporarily redirect `printf` calls to a buffer so I could easily send it over `elog` to the client?

If that's not possible, what would be the simplest way to modify the helper methods to end up with a buffer as output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you define your own version of printf and link to it **prior** to the libc version, your version will supersede the standard version.

You should also be able to supersede the standard version by using LD_PRELOAD to load a library that has printf defined.

To write your own printf, you will want to use stdarg functionality:

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int rv;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, fmt);

    if (redirect_printf)
    {
#ifdef HAVE_VLOG
        // If you have a vlog function that takes a va_list
        vlog(fmt, ap);
        rv = ...;
#else
        char buffer[LARGESIZE];
        rv = vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fmt, ap);

        log(buffer);
#endif;
    }
    else
    {
        rv = vprintf(fmt, ap);
    }

    return rv;
}
```

This simple version will truncate data when the final formatted output is greater than `LARGESIZE`.  If you don't want that, you can also call `vsnprintf` first with a NULL buffer to get the final size, do a dynamic allocation and then a second call to `vsprintf` to format the buffer.

Comment: Since this is an assignment and I'm only handing in the requires sources files, I can't control when anything gets linked.

Comment: @BenS - if you put printf in one of your source file, it should just work.

Comment: @BenS - updated to show you how can can turn redirection on/off via a global variable.

Answer (score 4):

You're wrong — `elog` supports format strings just like printf. Here's an example from Postgres source code:

```
elog(DEBUG4, "TZ \"%s\" gets max score %d", tzname, i);
```

So all you need is to add `elog` where there is `printf` using the same parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to modify the helper methods to call `sprintf()`.  Whether or not you can hack that in easily, I don't know.  Maybe

```
#define printf(...) sprintf(buffer, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Will do it for you.  You'll still need to define `buffer` for each helper function, and get its contents returned to whoever cares about them.

Comment: Yeah, there's about a dozen helper methods across two files so there's still quite a bit of work going this route. Also, wouldn't multiple calls then overwrite the previous sprintf? Or does sprintf append?

Comment: @Ben S, maybe there are already functions that do you what you want?  You can append with `sprintf()` since it returns the number of characters printed.  If you had a buffer for each function, that probably wouldn't be *too* hard to get working.

Answer (score 2):

If you can tolerate the use of a temporary file you could redirect standard out with the `freopen()` call:-

```
newstdout = freopen("/tmp/log", "w", stdout);
```

This will force all the printf's to be written to /tmp/log instead of the console output. At some convenient point later in your program you could then open the same file for reading:-

```
readfd = fopen("/tmp/log", "r");
```

and forward the contents that have been added using something like this:-

```
void forward_to_elog(void)
{
   int bytesread;
   char buf[100];

   memset(buf,0,100);
   do {
      memset(buf,0,100);
      bytesread = fread(buf, sizeof(buf)-1, 1, readfd);
      /* call elog(buf) */ ;
   } while(bytesread);

}
```

If you keep the file open you can call `forward_to_elog()` multiple times to incrementally forward the contents that have been added.

The `tmpnam()` function can be used to get a name for the temporary file if you don't want to have to statically code one.